# React Bootstrap select

Tags: reactjs

I'm to react and I'm getting this error when setting up my drop down list

```
        <FormGroup className="form-group">
                            <label htmlFor="services_dropdown">Service</label>
                            <FormControl
                                id="services_dropdown"
                                componentClass="select"
                                placeholder="select"
                                onChange={this.handleSelect.bind(this)}>
                                {serviceDropDown}
                            </FormControl>
                        </FormGroup>
                        <FormGroup>
                            <label htmlFor="tarifications_dropdown">Tarification</label>
                            <FormControl
                                id="tarifications_dropdown"
                                componentClass="select"
                                placeholder="select"
                                onChange={this.handleSelect.bind(this)}>
                                {usersDropDown}
                            </FormControl>
                        </FormGroup >
```

The error is giving me a hard time and this is it:

```
nput is a void element tag and must neither have `children` nor use `dangerouslySetInnerHTML`.
```

usersDropDown and servicesDropDown return a list  mapped from a list in state

Comment: Try putting `FormGroup` inside `<Form>` parent.

Comment: It's already inside form parent

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`FormControl` defaults to `input` when `as` property is not specified.

To use it as a `select`, you have to provide:

```
<FormControl
  id="tarifications_dropdown"
  componentClass="select"
  as="select"
  placeholder="select"
  onChange={this.handleSelect.bind(this)}
>
  {usersDropDown}
</FormControl>
```

[Form.Control API in docs](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components/forms/#form-control-props)